# ggforce geom_mark_ellipse spanning categorial / factor values

Tags: r, ggplot2, categorical-data, ggforce

I'm trying to use `geom_mark_ellipse` from `ggforce` package for circling a specific subset of my data. While one dimension of my data is numeric, the other is categorial and when trying to add a single ellipse `geom_mark_ellipse` draws two ellipses for each applicable value of the categorial dimension. This probably sounds more complicated than is, so here's a simple example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggforce)

set.seed(20)
my_data <- tibble(x = rnorm(20, 7, 5),
                  y = factor(rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 5), ordered = TRUE),
                  z = rnorm(20, 10, 2))

ggplot(my_data, aes(x, y, size = z)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_mark_ellipse(size = 1, aes(filter = ((y %in% c("c", "d")) & (x > 6) ))) +
    ggtitle("geom_ellipse with factor on y-axis")
```

This yields following chart:
[image: factor on y-axis -> two ellipses]

While I'd like to get a chart like this:

```
set.seed(20)
my_data2 <- tibble(x = rnorm(20, 7, 5),
                  y = rep(c(1,2,3,4), 5),
                  z = rnorm(20, 10, 2))

ggplot(my_data2, aes(x, y, size = z)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_mark_ellipse(size = 1, aes(filter = ((y %in% c(3, 4)) & (x > 6) ))) +
    ggtitle("geom_ellipse with numerical on y-axis")
```

[image: all numeric dimension -> one ellipse]

Certainly, a workaround is to coerce the factor into numeric - still: is there a way to "tell" `geom_mark_ellipse` to span factor levels (or other type of categorial variable values) or is this behaviour an intended feature?

Comment: Discrete axes automatically group variables. In the `aes()` of the ellipse, try putting `group = -1L`. The -1L is a convention, not a requirement.

Comment: Cool hint - that works, many thanks @teunbrand!